# Install Maven on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, maven

I'm trying to get tho [following code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111749/implementing-local-http-server) to run on Windows 7.

I can't get `mvn` to recognize `JAVA_HOME` and can't get `mvn` to appear as a command in the command prompt.

I get the following error when I try to run `"C:\Users\a\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin (2)\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\mvn"`

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

I have tried the following.
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin\` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\`

**EDIT: I would like a runnable script that sets up the environment.**

Here is a script

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
set MAVEN_HOME=C:\Users\a\Downloads\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin (1)\apache-maven-3.3.9
set path=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
set M2_HOME=
```

Comment: Downvoted because clearly you haven't even tried reading [the installation manual](https://maven.apache.org/install.html), which has all parts of your question covered.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo I have tried both of the following manuals https://maven.apache.org/install.html http://howtodoinjava.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-on-windows-7/  In fact I had a discussion with someone in chat about such.

Comment: Both articles say that you need JAVA_PATH pointing to JDK installation directory. Yours is pointing to JRE, which is not the same. They also both cover adding maven to PATH env. variable, which would allow you to execute it without typing the whole path. You can't expect a manual to help you if you don't follow it.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo  
Do you test the code with mvn? I tried C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55 with no success.

Comment: @guest are you willing to help with teamviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed OP's issue through a TeamViewer session, turns out a legacy environment variable `M2_HOME` was preventing maven from initializing properly.

Comment: pick a better name silly you have a decent amount of rep.  Unless you really like being called guest

Comment: in virtual machine, the end hosts are called guest. I think I maybe the same, just see the world as a guest, without breaking free to the hypervisor. maybe one day i will change my nickname, when i am closer to the truth.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to avoid permanently changing environment variable, save this batch file and run as needed.

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91
set MAVEN_HOME=C:\tools\apache-maven-3.3.9
set path=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%
cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

> Right click "My Computer", Properties, Advanced Settings. Environment
>   Variables.

**New: JAVA_HOME**

> Variable Name: JAVE_HOME
>   Variable Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60

Here is a list of programs that I have set paths to.
Also set the Environment Variable '**path**' to each that apply to you:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\apache-maven\src\bin;
>
> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;
>
> %M2%;
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin;
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60;
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\lib;
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre\bin;
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;
>
> %mvn%;

[image]

> Make sure you "**dropped your files**" in the right place.
>   [image]

---

Added: Aug. 05, 2016
[image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin]

The mvn variable is to: **C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin**

**NOTE:** The mvn variable is added to the environment variables, but also NOTE that the variable is added to the path as "%mvn%". Adding %mvn% to the path enables mvn to be called in a command LINE of text with arguments.

---

A **script**, with detailed instructions that must be followed, to set **Environment Variables** and their respective **PATH**'s.

```
::Paste this text into notepad
::Save as "myEnvironSetup.bat"; the ending must be .bat
::Right-Click this batch file you just saved, and Create Shortcut.
::Right-Click the shortcut you just created to elevate it: 
:: --- Right-Click, Shortcut Tab - Properties, Advanced, check box "Run as Admin"
::This modifier on the shortcut must be done in order to execute the "setx" command.


::RUN the SHORTCUT by double-clicking. Your system will prompt you, 
:: -- via User Account Control, to elevate the batch file. Accept.

::Your paths as you stated them - example directories
::C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin
::C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1

::Warning of elevated command prompt
echo This script must have been run from an elevated command prompt, created by a shortcut. If you did not create a shortcut and elevate it described in the instructions in this file, then do so now and re-run the shortcut to this batch file as Admin.

pause


::Set Directories HERE!

set "javadir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"
set "mavendir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.1.1"


echo You should have manually set the paths by now in the batch file!
echo Your set path for JAVA_HOME is: %javadir%, cancel now if incorrect!
pause
echo Your path for Apache_Maven is: %mavendir%, cancel now if incorrect!
pause


echo working...



::hard code REM setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60"

::Setting Environmental Variables here

setx JAVA_HOME %javadir%
setx JRE_HOME %javadir%\jre\bin
setx M2 %M2_HOME%\bin
setx M2_HOME %mavendir%
setx mvn %mavendir%\bin
setx MAVEN_OPTS "-Xms256m -Xmx512m"

::PATH setting

set PATH=%mavendir%\bin;"%PATH%
set PATH=%javadir%;"%PATH%
set PATH=%javadir%\jre\lib;"%PATH%
set PATH=%javadir%\jre\bin;"%PATH%
set PATH=%javadir%\bin;"%PATH%
set PATH=%mvn%;%PATH%
set PATH=%M2%;%PATH%



echo All Done.
pause
```

A preview of where my own personal Apache Maven (**Apache Software Foundation**) lives; my **PATH**:
[image]

Test Your %mvn% variable: should open the directory as the above image.
[image]

Comment: @William Sorry, found an error you might have not caught. I updated the script above. After you read this message, delete all previous messages above as I did already. Just replace the directories to where yours are. Note that the "mvn file" is in the directory of your apache-maven/bin, so as long as the paths are correct it should run 100%,

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pointing it to the JRE (Java Runtime Environment), instead of the JDK (Java Development Kit), as you would need to in order to get Maven to work properly ([see this SO post for information on the difference between the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)).

You will need to set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to this folder:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\

Or similar depending on your version of the JDK you have installed. If you do not have the JDK installed, you can download it from [Oracle's website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Comment: Do you test the code with mvn?  I tried `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55\bin` and `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55` with no success.

Comment: The backslash doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Please refrain from using different directories here in comparison to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from your error message:

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_91"
```

whereas JAVA_HOME environment variable should point to the JDK. You can change the environment variables as follows:

- Hit <kbd>Windows Key</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to open `Run` window.
- Enter command `control sysdm.cpl` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Navigate to `Advanced` on the `System Properties` window.
- Click the option <kbd>Environment Variables</kbd> at the bottom of the window.
- Under the `System Variables` list hit the <kbd>New</kbd> button.
- For `Variable Name` enter `JAVA_HOME` and for `Variable value` enter `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_55`

Now Maven should work properly.